# Side-by-side equations using minipage have offset

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, minipage, sidebyside

Using minipage to have side-by-side equations seems to give them an offset when one of them contains a fraction:

> [image: Blockquote]

Code here:

```
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
    \alpha (u,v) = \frac{N\!A}{n_s \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{N\!A \rho}{n_s}\right)^2}}
    \label{eq:alpha}
    \end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
    d = \alpha \rho z
    \label{eq:disparity}
    \end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{0.5cm}
```

Any idea how to fix this? or a better way to achieve the same results sans offset?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! `minipage`s are vertically centred by default. Try `\begin{minipage}[t]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the two objects have the same height (and depth). The simplest is to typeset each equation twice, one for output and one as a vertical phantom.

In the phantom I disable `\label`, so it won't be seen.

The optional argument is the fraction of space to reserve for the left equation.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newcommand{\sidebysideequations}[3][0.5]{%
  \begin{equation*}
  \begin{minipage}{#1\displaywidth}%
  \begin{equation}\vphantom{\def\label##1{}#3}#2\end{equation}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\displaywidth-#1\displaywidth}
  \begin{equation}\vphantom{\def\label##1{}#2}#3\end{equation}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{equation*}
}

\begin{document}

References: \eqref{eq:alpha}, \eqref{eq:disparity}

\lipsum[1][1-5]
\sidebysideequations[0.6]{
    \alpha (u,v) = \frac{N\!A}{n_s \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{N\!A \rho}{n_s}\right)^2}}
    \label{eq:alpha}
}{
    d = \alpha \rho z
    \label{eq:disparity}
}
\lipsum[2][1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works, thanks! Only issue is that the left-hand equation seems to have an extra indent - it's positioned further right than when using 'vanilla' minipage

Comment: @ajsc4 Optical illusion due to the minipage on the left being wider than the one on the right.

Answer (score 4):

Posted for Barbara who is having computer issues.

@Bernard has provided the canonical reason for the misalignment:
`minipage`s are vertically centered by default.  But the suggestion for
correcting the alignment, using the option `[t]`, doesn't have the
desired effect; the second equation is now just a bit higher than
the first.

@egreg has produced the desired result, along with a differently
formulated reason for the misalignment.  But there is a more compact
way to get this result as long as you understand the reason for the
misalignment and the way that (La)TeX measures the height and depth
of a math expression.  The `\vphantom` need contain just the
elements of the "taller" expression; it's not necessary to set the
whole thing twice.  And if one of the equations is taller on the top
and the other one deeper on the bottom, a minimal `\vphantom` can
be applied as necessary to each, to even out the height and depth.
(That is left as an exercise to the reader.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Using a \verb+\vphantom+:

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
    \alpha (u,v)
       = \frac{N\!A}{n_s \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{N\!A \rho}{n_s}\right)^2}}
    \label{eq:alpha}
    \end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
    d = \alpha \rho z
       \vphantom{\frac{N}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{N}{n_s}^2\right)}}}
    \label{eq:disparity}
    \end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

using the optional \verb+[t]+ for top alignment:

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
    \alpha (u,v)
       = \frac{N\!A}{n_s \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{N\!A \rho}{n_s}\right)^2}}
    \end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
    d = \alpha \rho z
    \end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Where does \verb come into it? Not sure if I'm missing something - egreg's method works for me while yours doesn't seem to.

Comment: @ajsc4 Barbara just used verb in the documentation to make `[t]` it isn't used in the code

Answer (score 1):

We need to set common baseline of two outputs of display math. This can be done by `\unskip\unpenalty` in `\vbox` just after the display math is closed and paragraph is finished:

```
\def\twodisplays#1#2{\vbox{\hsize=.5\hsize$$#1$$\par\unskip\unpenalty}%
                     \vbox{\hsize=.5\hsize$$#2$$\par\unskip\unpenalty}}

Test:
$$\twodisplays
  {
    \alpha (u,v) = {N\!A \over n_s \sqrt{1 - \left( N\!A \rho \over n_s\right)^2}}
    \eqno (1)
  }
  {
    d = \alpha \rho z
    \eqno (2)    
  }
$$
next text.
```