# How can I preserve vertical spacing around an equation in a minipage?

Tags: minipage

The following example:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
% outer minipages are not part of the test, and just demonstrate the inconsistency
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    
    This is an equation
    \begin{equation}
        x = 1,
    \end{equation}
    which ends in a comma.
    
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    
    This is a minipage equation\par
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
        \begin{equation}
            x = 1,
        \end{equation}
        \par\nointerlineskip\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}
    \end{minipage}%
    \par\prevdepth\tpd\noindent
    which ends in a comma.
    
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

where the `prevdepth` stuff is taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34982/41112, renders as

[image: output]

How can I make the column on the right match the one on the left, without removing the minipage? Note that the $x=1$ line is also misaligned, though only very slightly.

---

Edit: It turns out this is an XY problem, and the solution to my question above doesn't actually work for real problem. That is:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

This is some text that is long enough to wrap across multiple lines, or at least it ought to be. This gap is too big:\par\nointerlineskip\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}%
    \begin{subequations}\label{eq:tensor_tensor_tensor_left}%
    \begin{alignat}{2}%
    &
        (M \otimes_{\color{red} R} N) \otimes_{\color{blue} A} (P \otimes_{\color{red} R} Q) \nonumber \\
    \cong_{\color{blue} A} {}&
        ((M \otimes_{\color{red} R} N) \otimes_{\color{blue} A} P) \otimes_{\color{red} R} Q) \label{eq:ttt-left-assoc-1}
    \end{alignat}%
    \end{subequations}%
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}%
    \begin{subequations}\label{eq:tensor_tensor_tensor_right}%
    \begin{alignat}{2}%
    &
        (M \otimes_{\color{red} R} N) \otimes_{\color{blue} A} (P \otimes_{\color{red} R} Q) \nonumber \\
    \cong_{\color{blue} A} {}&
        M \otimes_{\color{red} R} (N \otimes_{\color{blue} A} (P \otimes_{\color{red} R} Q) \label{eq:ttt-right-assoc-1}
    \end{alignat}%
    \end{subequations}%
  \par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}%
  \vspace*{\belowdisplayskip}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
  \end{minipage}\par\prevdepth=\tpd\noindent
and some more unindented text. The gap above is too small. Toegther they add to the right amount.
\begin{alignat}{2}%
&
    (M \otimes_{\color{red} R} N) \otimes_{\color{blue} A} (P \otimes_{\color{red} R} Q) \nonumber \\
\cong_{\color{blue} A} {}&
    M \otimes_{\color{red} R} (N \otimes_{\color{blue} A} (P \otimes_{\color{red} R} Q) \label{eq:ttt-right-assoc-1}
\end{alignat}%
These two gaps are just right, and is a bit bigger than the one above

\end{document}
```

which gives:
[image]

Comment: This is a completely different problem than the quoted question.

Comment: @egreg: To my untrained eye they look the same, but I guess the type of skip around `equation` is unrelated to the `baselineskip` in that question?

Comment: Exactly so. And the problem is exacerbated by the nested minipage. Perhaps it's better if you explain your motivation.

Comment: The actual motivation is to put two sets of equations (and their numbering) -by-side without affecting the vertical spacing

Comment: I suspected something like that. I believe that the problem has already been answered on the site. For instance https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/550010/4427

Comment: Unfortunately the approach in that question doesn't work for me; it turns out I have `subequations` environments in my minipages, not `equation`; and for whatever reason that seems to break the `label`s

Comment: This question is relevant, but doesn't address the entire problem: [Spurious space above `align` environment at top of page/`minipage`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36954)

Answer (score 2):

Let me modify your example, so the second outer minipage is just to show the effect side-by-side with the first minipage. In the second minipage, the first line and the equation are in a minipage and the text that follows is outside.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
% outer minipages are not part of the test, and just demonstrate the inconsistency
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  This is an equation
  \begin{equation}
    x = 1,
  \end{equation}
  which ends in a comma.
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    This is a minipage equation
        \begin{equation}
            x = 1,
        \end{equation}
  \par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}%
  \vspace*{\belowdisplayskip}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
  \end{minipage}\par\prevdepth=\tpd
   which ends in a comma.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

However this could fail in several ways, because the skip after the equation might be `\belowdisplayshortskip` and a rather complex routine would be needed to ascertain it.

[image]

---

About the *real* problem, I suggest to manage along the lines of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/550010/4427

Prefer `\mathcolor{red}{R}` to `\color{red} R`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\sidebysidesubequations}[5][0.5]{%
  $$% Yes! We're consciously doing it
  \begin{minipage}{#1\displaywidth}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \begin{subequations}\label{#2}
  \noindent#3
  \end{subequations}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{\dimeval{\displaywidth-#1\displaywidth}}
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \begin{subequations}\label{#4}
  \noindent#5
  \end{subequations}
  \end{minipage}
  $$%
}

\begin{document}

This is some text that is long enough to wrap across multiple lines, or 
at least it ought to be.
\sidebysidesubequations{eq:tensor_tensor_tensor_left}{
  \begin{align}
    & (M \otimes_{\mathcolor{red}{R}} N)
    \otimes_{\mathcolor{blue}{A}}
    (P \otimes_{\mathcolor{red}{R}} Q) \nonumber \\
  \cong_{\mathcolor{blue}{A}} {}&
    M \otimes_{\mathcolor{red}{R}}
    (N \otimes_{\mathcolor{blue}{A}} (P \otimes_{\mathcolor{red}{R}} Q) \label{eq:ttt-left-assoc-1}
 \\
    & (M \otimes_{\mathcolor{red}{R}} N)
    \otimes_{\mathcolor{blue}{A}}
    (P \otimes_{\mathcolor{red}{R}} Q) \nonumber \\
  \cong_{\mathcolor{blue}{A}} {}&
    M \otimes_{\mathcolor{red}{R}}
    (N \otimes_{\mathcolor{blue}{A}} (P \otimes_{\mathcolor{red}{R}} Q) \label{foo1}
  \end{align}
}{eq:tensor_tensor_tensor_right}{
  \begin{align}
    & (M \otimes_{\mathcolor{red}{R}} N)
    \otimes_{\mathcolor{blue}{A}} (P \otimes_{\mathcolor{red}{R}} Q) \nonumber \\
  \cong_{\mathcolor{blue}{A}} {}&
      M \otimes_{\mathcolor{red}{R}}
  (N \otimes_{\mathcolor{blue}{A}} (P \otimes_{\mathcolor{red}{R}} Q) \label{eq:ttt-right-assoc-1}
  \\
    & (M \otimes_{\mathcolor{red}{R}} N)
    \otimes_{\mathcolor{blue}{A}} (P \otimes_{\mathcolor{red}{R}} Q) \nonumber \\
  \cong_{\mathcolor{blue}{A}} {}&
      M \otimes_{\mathcolor{red}{R}}
  (N \otimes_{\mathcolor{blue}{A}} (P \otimes_{\mathcolor{red}{R}} Q) \label{foo2}
  \end{align}
}
and some more unindented text
and some more unindented text
and some more unindented text
and some more unindented text.
\begin{align}
  & (M \otimes_{\mathcolor{red}{R}} N)
    \otimes_{\mathcolor{blue}{A}} (P \otimes_{\mathcolor{red}{R}} Q) \nonumber \\
  \cong_{\mathcolor{blue}{A}} {}&
    M \otimes_{\mathcolor{red}{R}}
    (N \otimes_{\mathcolor{blue}{A}}
    (P \otimes_{\mathcolor{red}{R}} Q) \label{eq:ttt-right-assoc-2}
  \end{align}
These two gaps are just right, and is a bit bigger than the one above

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't quite work for my real example. I've update my question, let me know if you think I should ask it as a new question. Thanks!

Comment: _"In the second minipage, the first line and the equation are in a minipage and the text that follows is outside."_  - oh, I completely missed this on first reading! Unfortunately I don't think this works for my two-column scenario

Comment: @Eric I added a solution for your real problem.

Comment: Thanks! I really do want separate subequation numbering for the left and right column. In my real version there is more than one labeled line on each side, but I figured that wasn't relevant to my layout concern

Comment: @Eric Added a new implementation. Of course, there can be no guarantee whatsoever on the inner alignments.

Comment: Superimposing the first half of your screenshot onto the second half shows that the spacings are not consistent: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL3ME.png; the space at the top of the first half is too big, while the one at the bottom of the first half is too small.